# Could not run component tests in Eclipse

Tags: java, junit, cucumber-jvm

we are using cucumber java for implementing component tests in our project.below is the test runner class.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(format={"pretty"})//, features="classpath:component/features/*.feature")
public class RunAllComponentCukesTest {
}
```

When I run component tests through this class,it was working fine.Now its not.I don't know whats wrong with this.I thought it might be with class path issue.I changed path and I just run all tests but in any way it's not working.If run from command prompt it is working fine.

I am getting following error message:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to create scenario runner
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.buildFeatureElementRunners(FeatureRunner.java:85)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.<init>(FeatureRunner.java:31)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.addChildren(Cucumber.java:90)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:418)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:112)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.<init>(ExamplesRunner.java:19)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.<init>(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:21)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.buildFeatureElementRunners(FeatureRunner.java:81)
    ... 21 more
```

I searched in google but this problem looks more generic so couldn't get the answer.

Comment: What version of cucumber-java and cucumber-junit are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question but just in case anyone happens to land here the solution is to use cucumber-junit 1.2.2

Ref: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/1083

Answer (score 2):

I started getting this error seemingly out of the nowhere as well.

**Problem:** It looks like there is an incompatibility between *cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner* and *org.junit.validator.PublicClassValidator* from **junit-4.12-beta-1.jar**.

PublicClassValidator throws an Exception with message:

> "The class cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner is not public."

I was only able to see this message displayed by stepping through with the debugger.

I was importing the latest 4.+ version of junit which is currently 4.12-beta-1. That is why the problem seemed to come out of nowhere. I guess I had not refreshed my dependencies in a while.

**Solution:** I reverted back to **junit-4.11.jar** and the error is no longer happening.

Comment: Thanks! More specifically cucumber-junit 1.2.0 isn't compatible with junit 4.12. I guess we need to wait for an update of either artifact.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the version of the eclipse it works fine in new eclipse.But I couldn't figure out what exactly the problem

Answer (score 0):

Got to Help/About Eclipse, click on "Installation Details". Select "Cucumber Eclipse Feature" and click in "Update...". Don't worry if your plug-in is up to date...

Now open your POM file (Maven Project) and set artifacts "cucumber-java", "cucumber-jvm" and "cucumber-junit" to version 1.2.2 at least (junit must be at least 4.11).